# Critical error GLIB in apache

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, glib

I have some problem with apache2 on my Debian server.

In error log I see:

```
(process:22196): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(process:22196): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'LassoNode'

(process:22196): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(process:22196): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'LassoNode'

(process:22196): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?
Also... After some hours apache down, and in error.log I see messages, that server reached MaxRequestWorkers but I rise MaxRequestWorkers to 1024 but it's not help for me.

Comment: Looks like a problem with http://lasso.entrouvert.org/ or maybe https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon. Maybe it's trying to dynamically register a module which has already been loaded? If you can't debug the issue yourself I'd suggest hitting their mailing list, or maybe filing an issue.